# Append text to column data in PostgreSQL if columns initial value is null

Tags: postgresql

Append text to column data in PostgreSQL if columns initial value is null.
Its not altering value.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's pretty unclear what you are trying to achieve, but:

If the column's value is `null` you can't "append" a value to it because any expression involving `null` yields null ( `null||'foo'` is `null`). In this case you just replace the null value with the new value:

```
update the_table
  set the_column = 'new value'
where the_column is null;
```

If with "*initial value is null*" you mean if the "*current value is an empty string*", then you would do something like this:

```
update the_table
  set the_column = the_column || 'this will be appended'
where the_column = '';
```

Which is identical to:

```
update the_table
  set the_column = 'this will be appended'
where the_column = '';
```

`null` and `''` are different things

Another option is to use the `concat()` function which will implicitly treat `null` values as empty strings:

```
update the_table
  set the_column = concat(the_column, 'this will be appended')
where ...
```

Comment: Then again, if it is a null or empty string, the end result is the same since '' || 'appended' will be just 'appended'. But depends on OPs actual needs.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen: you are right. I just wanted to make clear that appending to a `null` value will not work as intended.

Comment: Use concate(the_column, 'xyz') for appending to null column. set the column= the_column || 'xyz' does not work.